# How to add a sphere in tikzpicture with rotated coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put a sphere in the origin of my rotated coordinate, but in the end the sphere becomes distort. Any way to fix this?
Here is the [Overleaf code](https://www.overleaf.com/21443336vxpgpvdccmgg).

[image]

And the main file (you need 3dplot.sty too) is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim,amsmath}
%%%>

\begin{comment}
:Title:  The 3dplot package
:Zip: 3dplot.sty

The 3dplot package provides straightforward ways to define three-dimensional coordinate frames through which to plot in TikZ.  The user can specify the orientation of the main coordinate frame, and use standard TikZ commands and coordinates to render their tikzfigure.  A secondary coordinate frame is provided to allow rotations and translations with respect to the main coordinate frame.

The 3dplot.sty package can be found at `<http://www.heinjd.com/dev/latex/3dplot/3dplot.sty>`_.

Documentation for the 3dplot.sty package can be found at `<http://www.heinjd.com/dev/latex/3dplot/3dplot_documentation.pdf>`_.
\end{comment}

\usepackage{tikz}   %TikZ is required for this to work.  Make sure this exists before the next line

\usepackage{3dplot} %requires 3dplot.sty to be in same directory, or in your LaTeX installation

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  %generates a tightly fitting border around the work
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\begin{document}

%Angle Definitions
%-----------------

%set the plot display orientation
%synatax: \tdplotsetdisplay{\theta_d}{\phi_d}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}

%define polar coordinates for some vector
%TODO: look into using 3d spherical coordinate system
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}

%start tikz picture, and use the tdplot_main_coords style to implement the display 
%coordinate transformation provided by 3dplot
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]

%set up some coordinates 
%-----------------------
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%determine a coordinate (P) using (r,\theta,\phi) coordinates.  This command
%also determines (Pxy), (Pxz), and (Pyz): the xy-, xz-, and yz-projections
%of the point (P).
%syntax: \tdplotsetcoord{Coordinate name without parentheses}{r}{\theta}{\phi}
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

%draw figure contents
%--------------------

%draw the main coordinate system axes
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

%draw a vector from origin to point (P) 
\draw[-stealth,color=red] (O) -- (P);

%draw projection on xy plane, and a connecting line
\draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
\draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);

%draw the angle \phi, and label it
%syntax: \tdplotdrawarc[coordinate frame, draw options]{center point}{r}{angle}{label options}{label}
\tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\theta$}


%set the rotated coordinate system so the x'-y' plane lies within the
%"theta plane" of the main coordinate system
%syntax: \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phi}
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}

%draw Center of mass
\draw  (0,-0.2,-0.1) node[anchor=south]{$\boldsymbol{R}_{CM}$};

%draw normal vector
\draw  (0,0.35,0.6) node[anchor=south]{$\boldsymbol{n}$};

%draw theta arc and label, using rotated coordinate system
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\psi$}

%draw some dashed arcs, demonstrating direct arc drawing
\draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:90:\rvec);
\draw[dashed] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:90:\rvec);
\shadedraw [ball color=red] (0,0,0) circle(0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try: `\shadedraw [ball color=red,xscale=0.5] (0,0,0) circle(0.1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose, `tikz-3dplot` comes with `tdplot_screen_coords`, i.e.

```
\shadedraw [ball color=red,tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0,0) circle(0.1);
```

does the trick. Since there is a typo in your MWE (the package is `tikz-3dplot`, not `3dplot`), for the sake of reproducibility I add a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim,amsmath}
%%%>

\begin{comment}
:Title:  The 3dplot package
:Zip: 3dplot.sty

The 3dplot package provides straightforward ways to define three-dimensional coordinate frames through which to plot in TikZ.  The user can specify the orientation of the main coordinate frame, and use standard TikZ commands and coordinates to render their tikzfigure.  A secondary coordinate frame is provided to allow rotations and translations with respect to the main coordinate frame.

The 3dplot.sty package can be found at `<http://www.heinjd.com/dev/latex/3dplot/3dplot.sty>`_.

Documentation for the 3dplot.sty package can be found at `<http://www.heinjd.com/dev/latex/3dplot/3dplot_documentation.pdf>`_.
\end{comment}

\usepackage{tikz}   %TikZ is required for this to work.  Make sure this exists before the next line

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %requires 3dplot.sty to be in same directory, or in your LaTeX installation

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  %generates a tightly fitting border around the work
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\begin{document}

%Angle Definitions
%-----------------

%set the plot display orientation
%synatax: \tdplotsetdisplay{\theta_d}{\phi_d}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}

%define polar coordinates for some vector
%TODO: look into using 3d spherical coordinate system
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}

%start tikz picture, and use the tdplot_main_coords style to implement the display 
%coordinate transformation provided by 3dplot
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]

%set up some coordinates 
%-----------------------
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%determine a coordinate (P) using (r,\theta,\phi) coordinates.  This command
%also determines (Pxy), (Pxz), and (Pyz): the xy-, xz-, and yz-projections
%of the point (P).
%syntax: \tdplotsetcoord{Coordinate name without parentheses}{r}{\theta}{\phi}
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

%draw figure contents
%--------------------

%draw the main coordinate system axes
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

%draw a vector from origin to point (P) 
\draw[-stealth,color=red] (O) -- (P);

%draw projection on xy plane, and a connecting line
\draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
\draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);

%draw the angle \phi, and label it
%syntax: \tdplotdrawarc[coordinate frame, draw options]{center point}{r}{angle}{label options}{label}
\tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\theta$}


%set the rotated coordinate system so the x'-y' plane lies within the
%"theta plane" of the main coordinate system
%syntax: \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phi}
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}

%draw Center of mass
\draw  (0,-0.2,-0.1) node[anchor=south]{$\boldsymbol{R}_{CM}$};

%draw normal vector
\draw  (0,0.35,0.6) node[anchor=south]{$\boldsymbol{n}$};

%draw theta arc and label, using rotated coordinate system
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\psi$}

%draw some dashed arcs, demonstrating direct arc drawing
\draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:90:\rvec);
\draw[dashed] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:90:\rvec);
\shadedraw [ball color=red,tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0,0) circle(0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, things become more compelling if one draws these object in the correct order and does not let lines run into the interior of the sphere.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %requires 3dplot.sty to be in same directory, or in your LaTeX installation

\begin{document}

%Angle Definitions
%-----------------

%set the plot display orientation
%synatax: \tdplotsetdisplay{\theta_d}{\phi_d}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}

%define polar coordinates for some vector
%TODO: look into using 3d spherical coordinate system
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}

%start tikz picture, and use the tdplot_main_coords style to implement the display 
%coordinate transformation provided by 3dplot
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]

%set up some coordinates 
%-----------------------
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%determine a coordinate (P) using (r,\theta,\phi) coordinates.  This command
%also determines (Pxy), (Pxz), and (Pyz): the xy-, xz-, and yz-projections
%of the point (P).
%syntax: \tdplotsetcoord{Coordinate name without parentheses}{r}{\theta}{\phi}
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
\tdplotsetcoord{P'}{0.1}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

%draw figure contents
%--------------------

\shadedraw [ball color=red,tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0,0) circle(0.1);

%draw the main coordinate system axes
\draw[thick,->] (0.1,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0.1,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0.1) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

%draw a vector from origin to point (P) 
\draw[-stealth,color=red] (P') -- (P);

%draw projection on xy plane, and a connecting line
\draw[dashed, color=red] (P'xy) -- (Pxy);
\draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);

%draw the angle \phi, and label it
%syntax: \tdplotdrawarc[coordinate frame, draw options]{center point}{r}{angle}{label options}{label}
\tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\theta$}


%set the rotated coordinate system so the x'-y' plane lies within the
%"theta plane" of the main coordinate system
%syntax: \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phi}
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}

%draw Center of mass
\draw  (0,-0.2,-0.1) node[anchor=south]{$\boldsymbol{R}_{CM}$};

%draw normal vector
\draw  (0,0.35,0.6) node[anchor=south]{$\boldsymbol{n}$};

%draw theta arc and label, using rotated coordinate system
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\psi$}

%draw some dashed arcs, demonstrating direct arc drawing
\draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:90:\rvec);
\draw[dashed] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:90:\rvec);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]